# Setting up HKObserverQuery using Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Should it go in the AppDelegate.swift file?

I was looking at the apple documentation and saw their example:

```
let sampleType = HKObjectType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierStepCount)

let query = HKObserverQuery(sampleType: sampleType, predicate: nil) {
query, completionHandler, error in

if error != nil {

    // Perform Proper Error Handling Here...
    println("*** An error occured while setting up the stepCount observer. \(error.localizedDescription) ***")
    abort()
}

// Take whatever steps are necessary to update your app's data and UI
// This may involve executing other queries
self.updateDailyStepCount()
}

healthStore.executeQuery(query)
```

It wasn't very clear.

They also referred to the `initWithSampleType:predicate:updateHandler` which has the following declaration, but do I need to use this if I'm following the format above?:

```
init!(sampleType sampleType: HKSampleType!,
                    predicate predicate: NSPredicate!,
                updateHandler updateHandler: ((HKObserverQuery!,
                                     HKObserverQueryCompletionHandler!,
                                       NSError!) -> Void)!)
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you create a singleton for healthKit, you don't want to put all your code on the AppDelegate

Example
http://www.raywenderlich.com/86336/ios-8-healthkit-swift-getting-started